# Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

Cloned a rails application from github, works on the original dev's machine using the same version of rails (5.0.1).

Any rails command run from the app directory fails with:

```
Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile
```

Relevant Gemfile section:

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
```

Comment: You probably need to update your local bundler gem: `gem install bundler`

Comment: bundler --version reports 'Bundler version 1.13.7', gem update bundler says it is up to date

Answer (score 9):

[`git_source`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160-2014-03-28) was introduced in Bundler `1.6.0`.

To update bundler run:

```
$ gem update bundler
```

Comment: bundler --version reports 'Bundler version 1.13.7', gem update bundler says it is up to date

Answer (score 1):

In your console, run…

```
gem update bundler
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. 
$ gem update bundler
didn't help.
I installed one of missing gem via console, then used RubyMine Gem Manager to install rest of them (or sudo bundle install). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**My problem**

sample_app $bundle install --without production

Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile

sample_app $ ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]

**My solution**

```
/bin/bash --login
```

rvm use 2.4.0

```
/sample_app $ ruby -v
```

ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [i686-linux]

sample_app $bundle install --without production

Bundle complete!