# running Rails 5.1 console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

I installed a Rails 5.1 app on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I have to run a rails console

so I changed directory to cd /opt/www/myapp/current

and entered the command:

```
rails c production
```

but then I get this error message:

The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install

I tried to run the command with bundle:

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

but then I get this error message:

Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile
        from /opt/www/myapp/releases/20171017091250/Gemfile:3

I'm not sure what's going on.

Can someone help me run rails console on my production server?

Thanks a lot,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

[Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619741/undefined-local-variable-or-method-git-source-for-gemfile)

Or to save you visiting the link, try:

```
gem update bundler
```

git_source was added in bundler 1.6

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks, I updated bundler but I'm still getting this message when running rails c production: The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0

Comment: I think you should use: bundle exec rails c production

Comment: @Smek, if I try to run bundle exec rails c production, I get the error message: bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Comment: Well tit seems that you need to run bundle install first.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, I needed to run the command

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

as the 'deploy' user